# What Does the Process Tree Look Like Using Fork()?

Tags: c, fork, conceptual

Say, for example, we have the following executed in the shell:

```
ls | grep "abc" | wc
```

I understand how a child process would fork from the shell and how its a child, like this,

```
Shell (pid=12)
       \
        \
         ls (pid=13)
```

but I'm not sure how the pipe and the trailing commands fit in.  Are they also children of the shell, and not `ls`?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `pstree` utility?

Comment: For OP: get an idea from [**this code**](http://www.ladweb.net/src/ladsh4.c.html) how shell actually implements `|` operator. search this line in code: `if (!(newJob.progs[i].pid = fork()))` Then you came to know ls, grep, wc are child processes of shell...The code is not bash code but Bash do similarly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each component of the pipeline will be a child process of the shell.  If you use [`pstree -p`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pstree+1) from another terminal, you'll probably see something like this:

```
...
sshd(11)---bash(12)-+-ls(13)
                    |-grep(14)
                    \-wc(15)
...
```

(assuming you can run this whilst your pipeline is still running!)

However, note that all the components will form a single [*process group*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).

The piping itself is a feature of Linux (or whatever OS you're using), it's not a separate user process.  The shell creates some [*anonymous pipes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe), and hooks them up to the relevant file descriptors for each pair of processes in the pipeline.